# Using JavaScript to fit logistic regressions to datasets and obtaining beta-coefficients?

Tags: javascript, npm, logistic-regression

## Background

Using JavaScript, I need to fit a logistic regression to a dataset that I have generated. Specifically, I need to fit a multi-variate logistic regression, and I want to obtain the beta-coefficients for the model. How can I write this functionality in JavaScript?

## What I have tried

- `js-regression` ([npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-regression)): I've used the example logistic regression
  from this package, however it seems more oriented towards training a
  model and then classifying data.
- `machinelearn` ([npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/machinelearn)): I saw the logistic regression example in their documentation, but I have not been able to get it to work. I suspect also that this package is more oriented towards training a model and then classifying data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution

After sticking with `js-regression`, I delved into its source code and realised I had setup the structure of my training data incorrectly. Essentially, the `theta` attribute of the model generated using the `fit()` function is a list of your coefficients.

### Code

```js
let model = logistic.fit(training_dataset); // Generate the model
console.log(model); // Log the model
```

This outputted:

```js
{
  theta: [ ... ], // These were my coefficients
  threshold: 1,
  cost: ...,
  config: { alpha: 0.001, lambda: 0, iterations: 10000 }
}
```